# Python 2D list when indexing doesn't sem to work

Tags: python

I am practicing on a tic tac toe game in Python.  I have it all working, but when i am trying to traverse my board it does not work when trying to skip an index as it is the graphic.  It works fine when I change index manually, but not when doing a + in the index bracket.  Any help?

Working:

```
for i in range(n):
            win = True
            for j in range(n):
                if j == 1:
                    j = 2
                    if board[i][j] != player:
                        win = False
                        break
                if j == 2:
                    j = 4
                    if board[i][j] != player:
                        win = False
                        break
```

Not working when I try to add to the index instead of hardcoding it:

```
for i in range(n):
            win = True
            for j in range(n):
                if j == 1:
                    if board[i][j + 1] != player:
                        win = False
                        break
                if j == 2:
                    if board[i][j + 2] != player:
                        win = False
                        break
```

It seems to not actually add properly to index J and I can't figure out for the life of me why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

There's absolutely nothing wrong with 2D list indexing. You can figure this out quite easily if you do some [debugging](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), *especially* if you step through your code and inspect the values of the variables as the code is running. See
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953) Debugging is an essential skill for a programmer to have, and the sooner you teach yourself how to debug your own code, the better you'll be at programming.

In your first code, you have:

```
if j == 1:
    j = 2
    # do something with j

if j == 2:
    j = 4
    # do something with j
```

Let's assume `j == 1` is `True`, so you enter that block and set `j = 2`.
Then, when the interpreter is executing the `j == 2` line, _that is `True` because you set `j = 2` before.

In your second code, you never set `j = 2`, so the second `if` block isn't entered.

Comment: Sorry just getting back to this. I am used to some other scripting languages so this is throwing me off. 

It is supposed to evaluate each if statement.  It is looping and then compares. the first code is working as expected because it breaks before it gets to the 2nd if statement.
So, it doesn't ever  go into the 2nd if statement in my first code. it breaks out of the loop and goes to the next iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You re not doing the same thing in second code.
In your furst code, j= 2 and j= 4 .

```
if j == 1:
    j = 2
    .....                       
if j == 2:
    j = 4
```

In your second code, j= 3 and j= 6.
Because you are adding 2 and 4 to j which is already 1 or 2 .

```
if j == 1:
    if board[i][j + 2] != "player":
                       
if j == 2:
    if board[i][j + 4] != "player":
```

**So you can add 1 and 2 instead of 2 and 4 .**

Alternatively if you already know what value j should be as an index and don't want to change the value of j, you won't need j. Directly insert the value.

```
if j == 1:
    if board[i][2] != "player":
                       
if j == 2:
    if board[i][4] != "player":
```

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo on that paste.  Fixed it.  It still doesn't work with the addition piece which I can't figure out.  n = 3 by the way.

Comment: Is your first code working. Can you add the variable `board`  into your code.